# Python 3.x Tkinter, Entry field issue?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

[Pastebin - My Full Code](http://pastebin.com/imEEaGBZ)

I have an issue with my program that effects my entry fields.

With my password entry it works great, the input is stored to a StringVar and can be used to test whether it has been entered correctly.
When users enter an email address or new password in the admin settings page it doesn't work, the text variable is always null.

If you could help that would be much appreciated as this is going towards an important qualification.

Problematic Areas:

Change Function

```
#Function that changes the system email address
def ChangeEmail(page):

    global field_ChangeEmail
    newEmail = field_ChangeEmail.get()

    field_ChangeEmail.set('')

    print(newEmail)

    settingsDB = sqlite3.connect('Settings.db')

    action = ("UPDATE ADMIN_SETTINGS set SYSTEM_EMAIL = '" + newEmail + "' where ID=1")

    settingsDB.execute(action)
    settingsDB.commit()

    settingsDB.close()
```

Entry Field

```
    global field_ChangeEmail
    entry_ChangeEmail = tk.Entry(page, textvariable = field_ChangeEmail, justify = CENTER, fg = settings_EntryFontColour, font = settings_EntryFont)
    widthRatio = settings_AS_Column03Width
    heightRatio = settings_AS_RowHeight
    relativeX = settings_AS_Column03RelX
    relativeY = settings_AS_Row01RelY - 0.0009
    entry_ChangeEmail.place(width=screenWidth*widthRatio, height=screenHeight*heightRatio, relx=relativeX, rely=relativeY, x=-((screenWidth*widthRatio)*0.5), y=-((screenHeight*heightRatio)*0.5))
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to read through. Could you delete everything that isn't involved with your problem?

Comment: We can't be expected to read through all 893 lines of code to find a bug for you, especially when that code won't run exactly as posted.

Comment: I've updated the post with the two areas that are involved.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, though your use of `place` and variables for sizing is very, very odd.  I strongly encourage you to learn about pack or grid, it will make your GUI much, much easier to get right, and to maintain it over time. Place should never be used except when neither of the other two will work.

That being said, when I run the above code, and add a little extra to make it work, it works fine. `ChangeEmail` prints out the value that is in the entry widget, then clears the entry widget by setting the variable to an empty string. I assume that's what it's supposed to do.

If the text variable is getting set to null (`None`?), that is happening in some other part of your code.